# Can I create a Facebook app for a client and then remove myself?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

If I understand things right I must create a Facebook app if I want to, for example, use Facebook comments on a website. And I do this using my personal Facebook account inside developers.facebook.com.

So far so good.

But when developing a website for a client, I do not want to have all my clients apps connected to my personal Facebook account. So at my application at Facebook (developers.facebook.com/apps/) I can open an app I've created and then click on "Roller" and add Admins and Developers.

So, to my question, can I remove myself and give the application to my clients when I am done? And is this the "correct" way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove yourself from the app by doing this. Just make sure that your client accepts the developer agreements and is enrolled properly. An app needs to have at least one developer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but this is not the correct way in 2020 though.

You should create a Business Manager (BM) account of your client and your Agency.

Then you add an "app" under your client's BM and then share it to your Agency "BM".